# Fisher Transform: Use of the natural logarithm of negative number. How is it possible?

Tags: logarithms

I have the following equation, from http://www.mesasoftware.com/Papers/USING%20THE%20FISHER%20TRANSFORM.pdf

[image: Screenshot of the relevant part]

Because the parameters inside the log are (1+x)/(1-x), the output is always negative when x > 1.

But natural logarithms are only valid for positive number.

Anybody can explain that equation?

What am I missing?

Comment: Two possibilities: that x is restricted to being between -1 and 1; or that x is a complex number and you just have to pick a branch of the complex logarithm, which typically means that $\ln(-x) = \ln(x)+\pi i$ or similar.

Comment: It's clearly restricted to $(-1,1)$, so that values close to $-1$ go off to $-\infty$ and those close to $1$ go off to $\infty$. That would produce a two-tailed distribution, but it's not going to look like a bell in the middle if the input distribution looks funny in the middle.

Comment: The restriction $-1<x<1$ is stated in the first sentence on page 3 of the cited document.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I missed the range to which it was limited.